# exception error in attempt to create an sqlparameter collection using asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

i had this exception problem when i tried out implementing an sqlparameter collection. the exception says:

> **An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null
>   SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter[] objects.**

Here is also the source error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type
>   objects, not SqlParameter[] objects.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: The
>   SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type
>   objects, not SqlParameter[] objects.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 197:        if (p != null)  Line 198:            if (p.Any()) 
>   Line 199:                command.Parameters.Add(p);  Line 200:    } 
>   Line 201:
>
> Source File: c:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\WebSites\MusicStore\Pages\OverviewGuitarData.aspx.cs    Line: 199
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidCastException: The SqlParameterCollection only accepts
>   non-null  SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter[] objects.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.ValidateType(Object
>   value) 
>   +5734517 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add(Object value) +23 Pages_OverviewData.GetExample(SqlCommand command,
>   SqlParameter[] p) in  c:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 
>   2015\WebSites\MusicStore\Pages\OverviewGuitarData.aspx.cs:199
>   Pages_OverviewData.GuitarBrandsGridView_RowUpdating(Object sender, 
>   GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) in c:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 
>   2015\WebSites\MusicStore\Pages\OverviewGuitarData.aspx.cs:157
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnRowUpdating(GridViewUpdateEventArgs
>   e) 
>   +122 System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleUpdate(GridViewRow row, Int32  rowIndex, Boolean causesValidation) +792
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean 
>   causesValidation, String validationGroup) +877
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source,
>   EventArgs e) 
>   +89 System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37 System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs  e) +90
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
>   +37 System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +114 System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) 
>   +260  System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.
>   RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl,  String eventArgument) +15
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +35 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint,  Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1639

And here a part of my code where the sqlparameter originated:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["brandsConnection"].ToString())) {
        string query = "UPDATE [guitarBrands] SET type = @type, name = @name, image = @image WHERE id = @id";
        SqlParameter[] p = new SqlParameter[4];
        p[0] = new SqlParameter("type", newType.Text);
        p[1] = new SqlParameter("name", newName.Text);
        p[2] = new SqlParameter("image", newImage.Text);
        p[3] = new SqlParameter("id", id);

        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            GetExample(command, p);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            command.Parameters.Clear();
        }
    }

public void GetExample(SqlCommand command, params SqlParameter[] p)
{
    if (p != null)
        if (p.Any())
            command.Parameters.Add(p);//error is pointing here
}
```

Comment: One or more of your `SqlParameter` is `null`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: your query expects parameter with '@' and you are sending parameter with '@'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you really meant AddRange:

```
if (p != null && p.Any())
    command.Parameters.AddRange(p);
```

Besides, as commenters pointed out, make sure your parameter names correspond to your query:

```
p[0] = new SqlParameter("@type", newType.Text);
```

Comment: @Andrei - Yup this solution is correct. Also one more question, based on my code, what techniques would you recommend to improve this code?

Comment: @RockStar, well, there are a few nitpicks i could suggest. But really this would a good question to post on Code Review

Comment: @Andrei - here is the link to the code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/164092/update-sql-database-with-using-statement-and-sqlparameters

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the add. You must use AddRange instead.

```
command.Parameters.AddRange(p);
```